# How can I change the name of my Windows 8 app without starting a new project?

Tags: windows-8, rename

I'm working on a windows 8 app which is called (boter kaas en eiren) but I want to rename the whole project to (Tic Tac Toe). Is this possible? If it is how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to do a find in your entire project.  Below is a search for an application called "feedgrind":

[image: feedgrind search results]

Some notes on how the text is being used:

`App.xaml` - Your application uses this to display its name.

`Package.appxmanifest` - I'm not completely sure on this, but I believe Windows uses it to get information on your (deployed) app.

`Package.StoreAssocation.xml` - When you upload your app to the Windows Store, this name must match with the name that you have set up at the Windows Store. If you have not uploaded your app to the Store yet, this file may not exist.

`AssemblyInfo.cs` - Windows Explorer displays this information when you display the file properties of your exe.

`application.csproj` - Visual Studio uses this for the executable name (application.exe).

Obviously this answer is for a C#/ XAML/ Windows Store app. Your files may vary depending on your project type.